# What's the correct way to test this "setUp()" function inside this class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithmic-trading, trading

It's from the book L*earn Algorithmic Trading- Sebastien Donadio and Sourav Ghosh*

[src full code](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Learn-Algorithmic-Trading/tree/master/Chapter7) >> https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Learn-Algorithmic-Trading/tree/master/Chapter7

I'm supposed to test the

> [TradingStrategy.py](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Learn-Algorithmic-Trading/blob/master/Chapter7/TradingStrategy.py)

with this

> [TradingStrategy_ut.py](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Learn-Algorithmic-Trading/blob/master/Chapter7/TradingStrategy_ut.py)

From the **TradingStrategy_ut.py** I have to call the **setUp()** function to initialize the **TradingStrategy class**.

```
class TestMarketSimulator(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.trading_strategy= TradingStrategy()
```

I've tried and I don't understand how to make it work because the **TradingStrategy** **class** that's in the **TradingStrategy.py** file takes 3 parameters.

```
class TradingStrategy:
    def __init__(self, ob_2_ts, ts_2_om, om_2_ts):
        self.orders = []
        self.order_id = 0
        self.position = 0
        self.pnl = 0
        self.cash = 10000
        self.current_bid = 0
        self.current_offer = 0
        self.ob_2_ts = ob_2_ts
        self.ts_2_om = ts_2_om
        self.om_2_ts = om_2_ts
```

and every time I call the setUp() function I have this error:

```
x = TestMarketSimulator()
x.setUp()
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TradingStrategy_ut.py", line 72, in <module>
    x.setUp()
  File "TradingStrategy_ut.py", line 9, in setUp
    self.trading_strategy= TradingStrategy()
TypeError: __init__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'ob_2_ts', 'ts_2_om', and 'om_2_ts'
```

Comment: "From the TradingStrategy_ut.py I have to call the setUp() function to initialize the TradingStrategy class" - no you don't. `unittest` will handle calling that. You're supposed to be relying on the `unittest` framework for this stuff.

Comment: You don't need to call `setUp`. You just need to provide a correct implementation of `setUp`, including calling `TradingStrategy` with the correct parameters.

Comment: You are calling the `TradingStrategy`'s `__init__()` method which takes those 3 parameters. It seems like setup is trying to take the place of `__init__()` any way so you can probably just remove the funcation entirely

Comment: Thank you all !!

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**:

> python3 -m unittest **TradingStrategy_ut.py**

and also: edited **TradingStrategy.py**

added **None** after every parameter

```
  class TradingStrategy:
        def __init__(self, ob_2_ts=None, ts_2_om=None, om_2_ts=None): 
            self.orders = []
            self.order_id = 0
            self.position = 0
            self.pnl = 0
            self.cash = 10000
            self.current_bid = 0
            self.current_offer = 0
            self.ob_2_ts = ob_2_ts
            self.ts_2_om = ts_2_om
            self.om_2_ts = om_2_ts
```